# YAML bad mapping issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, serverless

```
list:
  handler: todos/list.list
  events:
    - http:
       path: todos
       method: 'use strict'
       const AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 
       const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(); 
       const params = {  
         TableName: "StreamData", 
         Item: { 
           ID: uuid.v1(), 
           name: data.name, 
           description: data.description, 
           price: data.price, 
           imageURL: data.imageURL }, }; 
         module.exports.list = (event, context, callback) => { dynamoDb.scan(params, (error, result) => { if (error) { console.error(error); callback(null, { statusCode: error.statusCode || 501, 
         headers: { 
           'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }, 
           body: 'Couldn\'t fetch the todos.', }); 
           return; } 
           const response = { 
             statusCode: 200, b
             ody: JSON.stringify(result.Items), }; 
             callback(null, response); }); };
       cors: true
```

I am new to yaml having a issue with line 10 TableName: "StreamData", says "bad mapping"if I remove the line the error moves up or down to the following line.

Comment: How did you end up with this, why do you think it should work and what do you think it should do? After `method` the input contains lines that seem to be JavaScript, not YAML. You can't just mix different languages in the input.

Comment: ive never used yaml before I was just trying to follow a tutorial to learn it.

Comment: That's why I'm asking. You probably misread something in the tutorial to end up with this code. The JavaScript likely needs to go into a different file. But we can't really help you unless we know what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The code you had written is not a YAML code. YAML is a declarative language and it does not contain commas(,) and semi-colons(;). Also, the YAML language does not use the equals symbol(=) for declaration. It only uses colons(:).

See YAML syntax here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html